# Removed argparse.py

Tags: python, ubuntu, argparse

I use Ubuntu 18.04. By mistake, I changed argparse.py file in usr/lib/python3.6. I couldn't fix it and I thought to remove it, so I could reinstall. Now I can't reinstall, whenever I try "`pip install argparse`" I get an error like this:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 279, in run
session = self.get_default_session(options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 74, in get_default_session
self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 91, in _build_session
index_urls=self._get_index_urls(options),
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 241, in __init__
self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 129, in user_agent from pip._vendor import distro 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 37, in <module>
import argparse ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'argparse'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module> sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 75, in main
return command.main(cmd_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 105, in main return self._main(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 224, in _main self.handle_pip_version_check(options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 146, in handle_pip_version_check timeout=min(5, options.timeout)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 91, in _build_session index_urls=self._get_index_urls(options),
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 241, in __init__self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 129, in user_agent
from pip._vendor import distro
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 37, in <module>
import argparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'argparse'
```

Could you please help me to fix this?

Comment: In a pinch, you can just grab https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/argparse.py and copy it into the `dist-pakcages` directory, but it may be simpler and safer to just re-install all of Python using your OS packaging tools.

Comment: reinstalling python is the best option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`argparse` is part of the standard library, not a third-party module. The standard library is *not* managed via `pip` (that is both its blessing and its bane).

So you have to fix or reinstall python itself.

Answer (score 0):

`argparse` is (since Python 3.2) part of the standard library. Just get the file from [the official github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/argparse.py) (I'm assuming cpython, adapt the version as necessary by selecting the correct branch, the link is for python 3.8) and put it back where the one you deleted was

Comment: You make it sound like `argparse` being added to the standard library is a recent development.

Comment: No. I make the statement that, _at the current time_, the module is part of the standard library. I did not write "it has been recently moved to the standard library". I'll reword just in case, anyhow